# ngx bootstrap datepicker doesn't support epoch date format?

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-ui, ngx-bootstrap

For example Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC in epoch date format is 1055545912454. But when I pass this value in bsValue I get undefined.

**Requirement**
my requirement are that date should be sent in epoch format in the api while making a server request. So, I have written a directive which converts any date format to milliseconds(changeDateDirective) and when this happens bsdatepicker returns undefined `<input changeDateDirective type="text" placeholder="Datepicker" class="form-control" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue" [minDate]="bsValue" [bsConfig]="{ showWeekNumbers:false, selectFromOtherMonth: true}" >` The same works in angular ui datepicker(uib-datepicker - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 0):

bsValue expects an object of [Javascript's Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so you have to pass a Date instance.
A Date instance can be constructed with a Unix Time Stamp(number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC)

```js
let date = new Date(1055545912454);
// Date 2003-06-13T23:11:52.454Z
bsValue = date;
```

Comment: Thanks but my requirement are that date should be sent in epoch format in the api while making a server request. So, I have written a directive which converts any date format to milliseconds(dateToMillis) and when this happens bsdatepicker returns undefined
<input dateToMillis type="text" placeholder="Datepicker" class="form-control" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue"
                    [minDate]="bsValue" [bsConfig]="{ showWeekNumbers:false, selectFromOtherMonth: true}"
                    >
The same works in angular ui datepicker(uib-datepicker)

Comment: Why you are not just converting Dates into Unix Time Stamps shortly before sending it to backend(i.e. at serializer)?

Comment: Because we will have to convert it again and again wherever we use datepicker, Instead I wanted a generic solution and hence the directive

Comment: Then just wrap your ngx-bootstrap-datepicker in a component. Then you can handle the convert there and can reuse the component everywhere in your app.

Comment: I can try that. Thanks !!

Comment: for time being I have used this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159487/how-to-change-the-date-format-in-the-datepicker-of-angular-ngx-bootstrap-inside.